# How to call an html form action attribute as method in vuejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, vue.js, express, backend

I'm try to create an app that take a image using drag and drop method, and immediately do the action specified in the form that containing it.

**index.ejs**

```
<form class="form" 
      id="form" 
      method="POST"
      action="/images/upload" <-- Llamar a esta acción
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      @dragover.prevent
      v-cloak @drop.prevent="addFile"
 >                            
 </form>
```

I tried this way, the result is capture the object but I don't know how to send the specified action.

**index.ejs**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    
    methods:{
        addFile(e) {
           file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]
           console.log(file)
           /// Llamar a action
    },
})
```

Finally, it is the rout that is managed the action form.

```
router.post('/images/upload', (req, res) => {
    uploadImage(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            err.message = 'The file is so heavy for my service';
            return res.send(err);
        }
        console.log(req.file);
        res.send('uploaded');
    });
});
```

Thanks for your assist.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@submit.prevent` for calling a method for your action.

Now for your question part:

As soon as you successfully drag and drop the image, either you can click the submit button with the help of **jQuery** or **refs** dynamically and call the action method or you can direct call the method of your action.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form class="form" id="form" method="POST" @submit.prevent="YOUR_METHOD_GOES_HERE" enctype="multipart/form-data" @dragover.prevent v-cloak @drop.prevent="addFile">                            
        </form>         
    </div>
</template>

<<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        YOUR_METHOD_GOES_HERE(){
            // place your action logic here
        }
    },
}
</script>
```